# If one makes a party for Bar Mitzvah during the 9 Days, can he serve meat?

Tags: halacha, meat, nine-days, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

As I understand, there is no mitzvah to make a se'udah for a Bar Mitzvah, unlike what occurs for a Brit, Pidyon Haben, Wedding or Siyum Masechta. Assuming that there is no siyum done, can a person serve meat during a Bar Mitzvah party made during the 9 Days?

Comment: If the bar mitzvah is on Shabbat, then there is no issue. We may make a meat se'uda even on Shabbat Chazon.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - This is a good solution, of course. Another easy solution would be to just do a siyum at the Bar Mitzvah. I was asking the question in general terms.

Comment: That would work. I have a friend whose birthday is 2 Tishrei. He didn't celebrate his b"m until Lech-Lecha. So that is also an option (also allows for the motzei Shabbat party with music et c.)

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=66

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rabbi Daniel Neustat [quotes](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/devarim.html) the Yad Efrayim 551:31 and Divrei Yatziv 2:238 as permitting meat for a Seudas Bar Mitzvah on the day of the Bar Mitvzah.

However, for this and all Seudas Mitzvah dispensations, if it is during the week that Tisha B'av falls out, only a minyan plus close relatives may partake of the meat and wine (Mishnah Berurah 551:77). Sha'ar ha-Tziyun 84 is more stringent allows only a minyan including relatives to partake.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a seudas mitzvah, the minhag would not be overridden and the prohibition  would still apply.

Comment: A source would be helpful.