# What to do if bar mitzvah is on a fast day

Tags: halacha, fast-days, meal-seudah, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Just out of curiosity, what does one do if his bar mitzvah falls on a fast day such as Yom Kippur or Tisha BeAv or any other of the 6 fast days?
Is the seudah passed on to the next day? The previous day? Or is it done anyway on the day on lesser fasts?

Comment: Does the seudah have any halachik status that you would think it pushes off the fast?

Comment: @mroll Maybe a better question might be Sheva Berachos? (Still not observed, but that’s besides the point.)

Comment: What do you mean by "his bar mitzvah falls on"?

Comment: @Alex Good point... I mean "his bar mitzvah IS on" or, its the day after and the fast was pushed off

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon But what do you mean by that? Do you mean that his birthday is on a fast day, that a planned meal is on a fast day, or something else?

Comment: @Alex His birthday

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon So are you assuming that a 13th birthday comes along with a mandatory meal, and that the mandatory meal must be precisely on his birthday?

Comment: @Alex, yes, exactly

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon It might help to [edit] the question to explain why you believe this is so.

Answer (score 1):

Just like bringing a sacrifice, arranging a סעודת מצווה - a Mitzvah meal (feast) does not have to be on the same day.

It's not a Mitzvah on its own and there are no obligations to fulfill at that feast, it is a custom based on the Gemmorah in Kiddushin (31a):

> "אמר רב יוסף מריש ה"א מאן דהוה אמר לי הלכה כר"י דאמר סומא פטור מן המצות **עבידנא יומא טבא לרבנן**"

The feast can be held on the same day, same week's Shabbos or any other date (or years later).

Comment: Um... That’s not at all where Seudas Bar Mitzvah comes from.

Comment: @DonielF Then where does it come from?

Comment: @ezra https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75951/9682

Comment: @Doniel The Maharshal quoted in the question you linked to mentions Al Berko’s source from Kiddushin